# Why phase margin considers only addition of negative phase?

Tags: control, phase-margin

When the phase margin of \$L(s)\$ is calculated, people calculate how much negative phase (or lag phase) can be added to the system \$L(jw)\$ until \$1+e^{-j\theta}L(jw)=0\$ for some frequency \$w\$.

But why only the addition of negative phase is considered? Multiplication by  \$e^{-j\theta}\$ rotates the Nyquist plot of \$L(jw)\$ clockwise until it touches \$(-1,0)\$ point, when closed-loop system becomes unstable. But also multiplication by  \$e^{j(2\pi-\theta)}\$ rotates the Nyquist plot of \$L(jw)\$ counter clockwise until it touches \$(-1,0)\$ point, when closed-loop system also becomes unstable.

From theoretical point of view they are same in my opinion, I guess there must be some practical reason related to the use of lag compensator or lead compensator.

Comment: "We" cannot "rotate" the Nyquist plot. It is a specific circuit which should exhibit such a behaviour. Therefore, my question: Have you an example circuit with such a positive phase slope (negative group delay)?

Comment: "multiplication by \$e^{-j\theta}\$ rotates the plot clockwise without changing the magnitudes of the vectors, and it is the vector of magnitude unity that can reach the point \$(−1, 0)\$ if rotated by the phase margin." this is a quote from the book Stability of Digital Control Systems by Fadali & Visioli 2009. In theory the word rotate the plot or Nyquist plot is always used when discussing phase margin. Lets say phase margin is 120 degrees, which means \$1+e^{-j120}L=0\$ at some frequency, but also \$1+e^{j240}L=0\$, so my question was why people define phase margin 120 and not 240?

Comment: @LvW I have edit the question following your comment. I hope my question is more clear now

Comment: The background for my first comment was just "wording". Of course, mathematically "you" can rotate the plot - but the question is if such a theoretical manipulation has a practical meaning. That means - my doubt is the following: Negative DC feedback is required for a stable bias point (-180 deg). Is there any practical circuit which has for rising frequencies a positive phase slope which could bring the loop phase back to zero deg.?

Comment: @LvW I don't know, usually in bode plot it is negative phase slope. Could you please explain why is it the case?

Comment: Perhaps, this helps?https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38424/is-a-filter-control-transfer-function-with-positive-phase-causal

Comment: Furthermore, you should consider that the "phase margin concept" does NOT always apply. It is nothing else than a simplified interpretation of the general Nyquist criterium. It does not apply to "conditionally stable" systems having a positive phase slope in a limited frequecy region. And it does, certainly, not apply to theoretical systems having a pole at infinity (positive phase slope at very large frequencies).